# Collect the multitude of "SMART - failure predicted" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical-answer

We have half a dozen questions asking about a boot-time SMART warning:

- [On booting my laptop warns me about failure of hard disk is imminent...can it be repaired or to be replaced..?](https://superuser.com/questions/512695/on-booting-my-laptop-warns-me-about-failure-of-hard-disk-is-imminent-can-it-be)
- [Is there a script to disable a SMART HARD DRIVE FAILURE IS IMMINENT MESSAGE](https://superuser.com/questions/129094/is-there-a-script-to-disable-a-smart-hard-drive-failure-is-imminent-message)
- [Warnings on HDD FAILURE](https://superuser.com/questions/443287/warnings-on-hdd-failure)
- [How to fix Failure predicted on Primary Slave: WDC](https://superuser.com/questions/341779/how-to-fix-failure-predicted-on-primary-slave-wdc)
- [S.M.A.R.T Failure predicted in harddisk](https://superuser.com/questions/531972/s-m-a-r-t-failure-predicted-in-harddisk)
- [What are reasons for "SMART Failure predicted on hard disk" error?](https://superuser.com/questions/576197/what-are-reasons-for-smart-failure-predicted-on-hard-disk-error)

Should we have a canonical question dealing with this? Or just collect the existing ones under one question? Some answers are effectively duplicates cross-question, so plain merging may not be appropriate.

Comment: Canonical questions are always appreciated.